# What do you call a ball of yarn/thread?

Tags: word-choice

An item for a cat to play with. I used the word ***clew*** from [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/clew) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clew), but people don't get it.

> 1. a ball of thread, yarn, or twine

> 1. a ball of thread, yarn, or cord

Which word can be used? A ***skein***? Or just a simple ***string***?

> A skein is a length of thread, especially wool or silk, wound loosely round on itself.

Comment: twine is a kind of string and yarn is wool. Wool comes in skeins (not a round shape), people often say a ball of yarn, because before knitting with it, they rewind it into a ball as a ball of yarn is easier to deal with when knitting than a skein. thread is for sewing and is not found as a ball. Both twine and yarn can be rewound in balls. Twine often comes already ball -ish shaped, over a cardboard core.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what your question is, because a ball of yarn or thread is called..."a ball of yarn", particularly if it's for a cat to play with ([example here](https://catbehaviorassociates.com/a-ball-of-yarn-isnt-a-safe-cat-toy/)).  Are you asking if there's a specific one-word answer?  Do you have a specific object you're thinking about?  Are you asking if there's a word that covers "any kind of thread/string/cord wound into a shape"?

Comment: @Lambie ‘Yarn’ in the uncountable sense may be wool, or it might be some synthetic fiber that has similar properties to wool (usually a polyamide of some kind), or, less commonly, it might be some other fiber (I have seen people knitting with silk or cotton before, and they still refer to it as ’yarn’).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn It may technically be that but in everyday language yarn is generally understood to be wool.

Comment: @Lambie Is this a US/UK thing? In the US, there's no presumption that yarn = wool. Typing in "yarn" gets me top results for cotton, acrylic, etc., as well as wool and wool blends. The only people who would consider all yarn as wool are the people who also consider all shiny fabric as silk (even if it's actually polyester sateen) and they're not going to realize that they're wrong anyway.

Comment: @user3067860 You can type in all you want, but Google is not a person. Are you a knitter? Because knitters use the term yarn all the time for wool. This is the most common use in AmE speech. Of course there are other types of yarns but not in the collocation being discussed here. Knitters can knit with blends, of course. Same thing.

Comment: @Lambie did you mean that when you want to say you used wool, you would say "I used yarn" or is it that wool is simply the most commonly used material for knitting, and that saying "I used yarn for knitting" is understood as wool just because it's the most common and the word "yarn" is underspecified?

Comment: @Lambie I agree that "yarn" is "the stuff knitters use", but (at least the British knitters I know) would use "yarn" if they were knitting with wool, silk, synthetic, or a mixture.  Saying "yarn is wool" is an over simplification which I think is unhelpful to a learner.

Comment: @stangdon  Yes, I was seeking for a specific one-word answer, describing 'any kind of thread/string/cord wound into a shape'. Most preferrably associated with cats playing.
The red ball on the pic below describes well what I'm thinking about.

Comment: @Lambie I'm a knitter as well as a crocheter and sewer. You said "yarn is generally understood to be wool". I've gone into specialty yarn stores and they have the cotton yarn and alpaca yarn and bamboo-mix yarn on the shelf under the label "yarn" right next to the wool yarn. IME knitters and other fiber-based crafters are _more_ likely to differentiate between fiber content (wool, cotton, poly, alpaca, bamboo, ...) and form (yarn, roving, etc.).

Comment: @Tuffling_Tony  Thanks for the clarification!  I don't think there is a single word that means exactly what you want.  *Skein* is too specific.  Cats normally play with a "ball of yarn".

Comment: @user3067860 It does not matter about the different kinds of yarn. Cats play with balls of yarn, of whatever type.

Comment: @Lambie I agree, which is why I'm so confused that you said that yarn = wool.

Comment: @user3067860 Cats play with balls of yarn and the yarn is wool. Look at Michael's answer. This is just not controversial.

Comment: @Lambie How can you tell the stuff in the picture is "wool" as opposed to poly, cotton, etc.? (Cats play with yarn, yes. Cats play with all types of yarn--wool, cotton, poly, etc., they don't really seem to care what the fiber content is.) The only part here that's controversial is that you said all yarn = wool.

Comment: @user3067860 Because that is what cats play with. They ain't textile specialists. Michael agrees. Ball of yarn aka a ball of wool. He said: My UK cat loves playing with a ball of wool or other soft yarn. This is just not controversial as a cliché about cats and yarn/wool.

Comment: I think Lambie might be trying to say that "wool" is used colloquially for any kind of "yarn" (even if the yarn is in fact not literally wool but synthetic), rather than that "yarn" literally means wool and only wool.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Clew" is correct. However, it is not very common (some people consider it old-fashioned or archaic), so many people might not know it. Even if they do know it, they might confuse it with its homonym "clue".

- You can also say "skein", although that word is used less often with spherical shapes and is also somewhat rare.
- The word "string" describes a type of cord and not the shape it takes.
- If you want to use a word that's widely understood, you can simply say "ball of [material]", as in your title.

Comment: "Clew" as "clue" can be not only a mistake or confusion but also a [rare and/or archaic variant spelling of "clue"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/clew), as in the several ["Nick Carter's (adjectival) Clew"](https://gutenberg.org/ebooks/search/?query=clew&submit_search=Go%21) stories and other mystery novels/stories with "Clew" in the title, as well as many instances of ["discover some/the/a clew"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22discover+*+clew%22+site%3Agutenberg.org) in the text.

Comment: Clew and Clue are the same word.  Ariadne gave Theseus a "clew" to guide him back through the laberinth. The sense transferred to "a guide or assistance to a tricky problem"  and later the spelling was modernised.

Comment: @JamesK Yes, they're the same in that sense. They're different in that the "clue" spelling isn't typically used for the "ball of thread" meaning. (I believe that it used to be.)

Comment: The OED says that "clew" is "the regular name in Scotland and north of England", so there may be places where it's more understandable.  But in American English, for example, it likely wouldn't be understood.

Comment: This answer is incredibly misleading, and/or just "wrong".  Clew is archaic, or, extremely regional/specialized.

Comment: @Fattie Agree completely, this is totally misleading. Especially for what a cat plays with!

Comment: indeed @Lambie  .  Also, I'm not totally sure that, amongst those who use "clew", that it actually or usually means literally a ball-shaped arrangement.  And the confusion with the use on sailboats compounds this darned issue!  (HAR)

Comment: @Fattie I have to say many of these comments are clew-less. :)

Comment: @Fattie I looked in three major dictionaries (M-W, AHD, and Collins), and not one indicates that "clew" with this meaning has any restrictions on use. If you believe that it is "archaic, or, extremely regional/specialized", please cite evidence (beyond "not very common", which is already in my answer) and I'd be happy to edit my answer.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Huh, I'm surprised they don't indicate it as being archaic. The relevant entry in the Chambers dictionary is "A ball of thread, or the thread in it (archaic)" although interestingly enough the verb form "To coil up into a clew or ball" isn't listed as archaic.

Comment: Hi March.  Google / google books to see it is unused.  You can see any number of articles that point out it is only used in Scotland or only historically. Regarding in spoken language (which is what the question is about), as with every single QA on this site you can only seek opinion on that, and it's clearly archaic (as literally every commenter on this page has stated). Google "is clew archaic" *"The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language (5th ed.) says this use of “clew” is chiefly British, but the British dictionaries we checked describe the spelling as rare or archaic.*..."

Comment: @Fattie I don't doubt that you can find some people who say it's archaic. (I did note in my answer that it was "not very common".) I'll stick with the major dictionaries that say it isn't. (BTW, a quick check of [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clew&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), as you suggest, indicates that "clew" is just as popular now as it was 100 years ago and that its use is trending upward.)

Comment: @Fattie In any case, I've edited my answer. Hopefully that takes care of the issue.

Comment: its so good i added a bounty!

Answer (score 36):

My UK cat loves playing with a **ball** of wool or other soft yarn.

[image]

In my kitchen cupboard is a **ball of string**. Some people use 'twine' synonymously with 'string'; others use 'twine' to be a stronger kind of string.
[image]

A skein is not ball-shaped:

[image]

#### Most people won't know what a 'clew' is.

.

Comment: I think it’s worth noting that since knitting is now much less common than it used to be, many (especially younger) native speakers will likely not really be aware of the difference between these things either. Personally, I’ve never even heard of a ‘cake of wool/yarn/twine’, I don’t think I’ve ever actually seen a hank of wool before, and my only association with skeins is a vague notion that they’re sort of fluffy and loosely coiled. So I would probably have called all four woolly bundles in the last image balls of wool, and might have called the first two skeins.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I have seen all of those shapes at knitting or craft stalls in an indoor market here in Bristol (UK), and you can order cakes here:  https://www.woolwarehouse.co.uk/blog/yarn-cakes/ and here https://www.lovecrafts.com/en-gb/l/yarns/cake-yarn (just examples)

Comment: Oh, I’m not saying they’re not correct or don’t exist, just that lots of people nowadays don’t venture into craft stalls and will likely not be very aware of them. They’re words that were once as common and as much a part of everyday life as ‘saucepan’ or ‘handlebar’, but have now moved towards being technical terms, in the same way that names for many farming or riding tools have become technical terms that most people no longer know.

Comment: re: Wool vs. Yarn - Americans might still call it wool if it is, in fact, wool.  Much yarn sold in the US today is not actual wool, but cotton or other plant fibers, or synthetic.  Actual wool can be a problem for people with allergies, so other materials are often preferred since they're far less likely to cause such reactions.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - I am used (UK) to thinking that 'yarn' is a generic term for any 'stringy' stuff used in weaving or knitting, and Collins Dictionary agrees: _any fibre [fibre], as wool, silk, flax, cotton, nylon, glass, etc., spun into strands for weaving, knitting, or making thread_

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yeah, I'd agree with that.  But as an American, I don't think I'd use "wool" to refer to anything that isn't actually made of wool.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - ' I don't think I'd use "wool" to refer to anything that isn't actually made of wool.' - me neither. I believe wool can be called yarn in the US, but not the other way around. I hope I haven't implied anything else?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "My UK cat loves playing with a ball of wool. Americans might call it a 'ball of yarn'." -- This implies that UK people wouldn't use "ball of yarn". What would you call it in the UK if it was made out of cotton or synthetic fibre? Or if you didn't know what it was made of? Americans would still call it a "ball of yarn", but your phrasing implies that in the UK it might still be a "ball of wool" even without definite fibre identification. (I can't tell what the item in the picture what is made of, but given the color my first guess would be synthetic.)

Comment: @R.M. - thanks for the heads-up. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I'll admit -- I haven't a clew.

Comment: In the UK, a ball of soft yarn suitable for knitting would probably be called "wool" even if it was actually synthetic.  This is an example of where the "normal" English of people like me and Michael, and the technical English differs.  I know people who would **never** call an acrylic fibre "wool", and there are people who would never call writing HTML "programming"  but non-specialists use language in a less precise way.

Comment: @JamesK - I know people who call any sewing thread 'cotton' whether it is that fibre or man-made, or a mixture.

Comment: Referring to the photo, I think there's a risk that some of the usage might be local. I think we can probably all agree that yarn of some sort (i.e. wool or otherwise) rolled without a core is a ball (with room for debate if it is not fairly round), and with a core it would be likely to be a spool or possibly a cone (for machine knitting) or a reel (for very light stuff). But I'd have called yarn wound on the forearm a skein, with "hank" kept for something less structured e.g. a hank of horsehair. But I learnt the terminology at my mother's knee, and she was from the Northern Welsh Marches.

Comment: I would use describe the final photo as "ball, skein, ball, ball".

Comment: yeah i only think of bailer twine, and I wanted a shawl made out of wool, the difficulty i had finding wool, as I was shown the shelves full of artificial fibres and mixes.  It seems anything hand knitted is made from "wool"

Comment: I don't get people's comments here at all. **Cats play with balls of yarns or balls of wool**. The rest is simply not germane to the topic.

Comment: From my UK perspective, "yarn" feels like either a technical term that only knitters/crocheters would use, or an American term; whereas the general public would nearly always just say "wool".

Comment: I live in the US and always have. I have never knitted but several family members do or did. I would call fiber for knitting "yarn", but would only use "wool" for fiber derived from sheep's hair (except fort "steel-wool" or the like). Also, I think that when "clew" refers to string or yarn it does not imply a ball. Surely in the nautical expression "to clew up", meaning "*raise a sail with a light line*", the line is not in a ball. Aridanie's clew was stretched out through the maze.

Answer (score 11):

## It's just a ball of yarn

UK native English speaker here.

"Ball of yarn" is an everyday phrase. I've never heard anyone refer to this object as anything else.

I've also never heard of the words "clew" or "skein" before reading this question, which suggests they're either archaic, niche or particularly fancy terms that wouldn't be used in common parlance.

Not everything needs/has a single word to describe it! :)

Comment: the fully correct answer

Comment: AmE speaker here. It's exactly the same thing American English AND cats play with them.

Comment: *Skein* is pretty common in textile techniques (knitting, crochet, etc.)  I guess that counts as "niche", but it's not so obscure it wasn't used metaphorically in [the title of a 1985 book.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/With_a_Tangled_Skein/MoLdOBwGbrcC?hl=en&gbpv=0)

Comment: And by the way, it's actually dangerous as the yarn or wool can become lodged in their throats.

Answer (score 8):

In my experience (living in the United States), yarn that has been wound into a ball is just called "a ball of yarn." I don't know of any other common word or phrase for it. Likewise, string or twine that's been wound into a ball would just be called "a ball of string" or "a ball of twine."

I'm not sure exactly what the difference between yarn, string, and twine is. To me, "yarn" sounds like a soft and comfortable material suitable for knitting clothes out of—usually made out of cotton, wool, or acrylic. "String" sounds like something which wouldn't be good for making clothes out of, and which would most likely be made out of cotton. "Twine" sounds like something made out of a tougher fiber than cotton.

Comment: In the 1960s my father used to wear a garment called by Brits a 'string vest', which I think one could bring to mind by imagining a 'mesh wife-beater'. It wasn't made out of string such as that used for tying up parcels. He would not strip to the waist at the beach and I still remember the diamond sunburn patterns he acquired. Caution: I Googled for images of string vests; they are apparently still a thing; they seem to be esteemed by 'jock' type men; the pictures made me shudder.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey String pants you say?

Comment: @CGCampbell - yes, [they exist](https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/643347429/classic-string-y-fronts-briefs-underwear) - call me weird, but I do not care overmuch to look at those pictures.